# Unexpected Token but not sure as to why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure why I am getting an `Unexpected Token` error. I can't seem to see the error. Unless

Line 41 is: `}.bind(this),` right after `this.setState`

```
ERROR in ./app/views/components/navbar.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/app/views/components/navbar.js: Unexpected token (41:4)
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({logoPath: response});
            }.bind(this),
            error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this),
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2817:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2811:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:937:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:718:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:4305:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:504:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:484:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:415:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:397:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:360:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1206:16)
    at Parser.parseExprListItem (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3692:24)
    at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:580:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:543:29)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:514:15)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:484:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:415:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:397:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:360:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:324:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1874:19)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3507:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2208:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlock (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2189:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseFunctionBody (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1125:22)
    at Parser.parseFunctionBody (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3494:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseMethod (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1094:8)
    at Parser.parseClassMethod (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:3735:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseClassBody (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2456:10)
 @ ./app/views/components/layout.js 17:14-36
```

Reactjs Component

```
class Logo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            success: (response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({logoPath: response});
            }.bind(this),
            error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this),
            data: {
                location: this.props.location
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="logo">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src={ this.state.logoPath } alt="Home"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised by the error, though I notice that *ArrowFunction* is an *AssignmentExpression* whereas *FunctionExpression* is a *PrimaryExpression* ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-expression-rules)), so arrow function expressions aren't direct drop-ins for `function` function expressions. Still surprised.

Two options for you:

1. You don't need those `.bind(this)` calls. Arrow functions close over the `this` in the context where they're created (just like closing over a variable). So you can solve the error simply by removing those `bind` calls.

   Example:

   ```js
   var foo = {
     name: "foo",
     doSomething() {
       setTimeout(() => {
         log("this.name = " + this.name);
       }, 0);
     }
   };
   foo.doSomething();

   function log(msg) {
     var p = document.createElement('p');
     p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
     document.body.appendChild(p);
   }
   ```
2. Alternately, if you needed `bind` (perhaps to curry arguments; the `this` part will be ignored), put parens around the arrow function:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       success: ((response) => {
   // ----------^
       }).bind(null, arg0, arg1/*...*/)
   // --^      ^^^^-- will be ignored, arrow functions inherit `this`
   });
   ```

   Example:

   ```js
   var foo = {
     name: "foo",
     doSomething() {
       setTimeout(((arg) => {
     // ----------^
         log("this.name = " + this.name + ", arg = " + arg);
       }).bind(null, "bar"), 0);
     // ^      ^^^^-- ignored, could be anything
     }
   };
   foo.doSomething();

   function log(msg) {
     var p = document.createElement('p');
     p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
     document.body.appendChild(p);
   }
   ```

Comment: So that means that when I want to change the context from `this` to something else, I'll have to use classic function notation?

Comment: @Fidel90: It's not "context," but yes, if you want the function to have varying values for `this` depending on how you call it, you can't use an arrow function. Arrow functions have no `this` binding of their own, so there's no mechanism for setting `this` when calling them. Instead, they *close over* `this` just as though it were a variable.